# Accessing active directory through a SSH tunnel?

Tags: active-directory

I'm able to use putty to tunnel into my University network and connect to all the local servers in my university. I can also the university proxy to browse internet. I was wondering if there is any software that I can use, which will enable me to access the active directory files through the SSH tunnel remotely.

Comment: What do you mean by Active directory files? AD is a databse used to store credentials accounts etc, what do you want to retrieve?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are talking about using SSH to proxy connections to your Universities AD servers?  For example, running a tool like Active Directory Users and Computers on your home computer through SSH tunnel?  ADUC uses RPC to communicate with DC's, and I would think you would have a hard time getting all the RPC ports through the SSH tunnel.

You might be better off using a RDP session through a SSH tunnel to the Domain Controller or another server in your environment.  More information on what you're trying to do would be very helpful in completing this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am on the wrong path, but the [active directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_directory) is a "directory service" which provides authentication, and not exactly files.

Do you want to access files on "shared folders"?

For that, more information is needed:
- How do you tunnel? Is this a VPN-Connection? Have you tried \\SERVERNAME.COMPLETELY.WRITTEN\foldername ?
- Do you ssh directly into a machines commandline? What machine?